# LINQ using Join on a long and long[] typed properties (one to many variation)

Tags: c#, linq, join, lambda, one-to-many

I am trying to find a better way to write an effective JOIN using LINQ and Lambda expressions, hopefully using a Join, to work with the following types:

```
public class Patent
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string YearOfPublication { get; set; }
    public long[] InventorIds { get; set; }
}

public class Inventor
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The subsequent data is being created as such:

```
public static class PatentData
{
    public static readonly Inventor[] Inventors = new Inventor[]
    {
        new Inventor(){
            Name="Benjamin Franklin", Id=1 },
        new Inventor(){
            Name="Orville Wright", Id=2},
        new Inventor(){
            Name="Wilbur Wright", Id=3}
    };
    public static readonly Patent[] Patents = new Patent[]
    {
        new Patent(){
            Title="Bifocals", YearOfPublication="1784",
            InventorIds=new long[] {1}},
        new Patent(){
            Title="Flying machine", YearOfPublication="1903",
            InventorIds=new long[] {2,3}}
    };
}
```

To iterate through all the inventors for a particular patent, I am using the following code below.

```
IEnumerable<Patent> patents = PatentData.Patents;
IEnumerable<Inventor> inventors = PatentData.Inventors;

foreach(Patent p in patents)
{
    var iall = inventors.Where(i => p.InventorIds.Contains(i.Id));
    foreach (Inventor i in iall)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(p.Title + ": " + i.Id);
    }
}
```

Although the code above works fine, I would really like to use a LINQ Join statement. The problem, obviously, is that the LINQ Join statement will grumble about the different types (long and long[]) which are primary and foreign keys respectively.

The code that I would have preferred to use of which I can't seem to get working, is follows:

```
Patent [] patents = PatentData.Patents;
Inventor [] inventors = PatentData.Inventors;

var result = patents.Join(inventors, patent => patent.InventorIds, inventor => inventor.Id, (patent, inventor) => new
{
    patent.Title,
    inventor.Name
});
```

This is failing, quite rightly, with the following error:

*error CS0411: The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Join(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func, System.Func, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.*

So, my question is:

How can I repair the code that has the error to work with the Join statement when used in conjunction with the two types; Patent and Inventor - without modifying the types at all? Is it even possible?

I appreciate that I can change the types so that they are better structured, but humour me for a moment.

Comment: Why are you using ids here? Why doesn't `Patent` have something like `Inventor[] Inventors`?

Comment: That is how I would normally do it, but my question was, how can I use the types as is, with the Join statement. Believe it or not, I have client data similar to above so it is a proactive question for when I need to face it at work :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a join for each individual patent:

```
var query = from patent in patents
            from inventorId in patent.InventorIds
            join inventor in inventors on inventorId equals inventor.Id
            select new { patent.Title, inventor.Name };
```

Of course, if you could avoid using the `Id` part of your model and instead associate inventors of a patent directly with `Inventor` objects, that would be simpler.

Comment: Both yours and Joachim's answer below give the same results as expected so I appreciate all responses so far. Although it is not using the Join expression on the IEnumerable type, it is one solution.

Comment: @SolidRegardless Actually, this is using `Enumerable.Join()`, it's just a different way to write it.

Answer (score 1):

Jon's answer is exactly what you need. But if you really want to use the `Join()` (and `SelectMany()`, which is represented by the second `from`) method directly, and not hidden behind the LINQ query syntax, you can do that too. Although in this case it's much more complicated:

```
patents.SelectMany(patent => patent.InventorIds,
                   (patent, inventorId) => new { patent, inventorId })
       .Join(inventors, x => x.inventorId, inventor => inventor.Id,
             (x, inventor) => new { x.patent.Title, inventor.Name })
```

Comment: thanks for that example. It is actually quite readable in itself but I shall certainly consider using the cleaner LINQ queries for my future endeavours!